# How to not redirect if is from social media site with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

How do I not force a redirect if it's from a social media site like reddit,facebook & twitter? Currently my setting is set to redirect any direct access to image files but I don't want to redirect if it's from social media sites so it can fetch image preview.

```
proxy_cache_path /var/www/img.example.com/htdocs/cache-store levels=1:2 keys_zone=pixstore:10m max_size=5g inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;
server {

    server_name img.example.com www.img.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/img.example.com.access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/img.example.com.error.log;

    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    location / {
        proxy_cache pixstore;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090;
        proxy_redirect off;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 7d;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
    }

    location ~ "^/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/((?<filenum>\d+)[^/]+\.(jpg|png|webp))$" {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090;
    return 301 http://view.example.com/artwork/$filenum;
    }

}
```

Comment: we need more specific information about what you want, moreover is there a business for?

Comment: The configuration in your question does not match the "Currently my setting is" statement. Please make sure your question is consistent.